# Запрет масштабирования текста в мобильных браузерах

Tags: google-chrome, android, html, javascript, css

Добрый день.
Заметил тут одну досадную вещицу - мобильный ГуглеХром (проверял на Дроиде) балуется увеличением текста, где ему покажется необходимым. Это может исправить каждый юзверь у себя в настройках браузера (в специальных возможностях можно выкрутить масштабирование текста до 50%), но мне хотелось бы чтобы это правилось самостоятельно, без участия пользователя. Есть ли какие-то способы поправить сие досадное положение?

Comment: а зачем? ведь изменяет для того что бы пользователю было удобнее читать, и я даже не хочу говорить про dp,px,sp etc, достаточно сказать что зрение у всех разное и удобный размер текста для чтения у всех разный, зачем портить человеку удобство чтения?

Comment: Для удобства чтения есть зум. А с увеличением размера шрифта где вздумается портится вид сайта.

Comment: Так нет решения данной задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как это ни странно решение следующее.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

- `initial-scale=1.0` — масштаб (зум, приближение) при загрузке (начальный).
- `maximum-scale=1.0` — масштаб максимальный.
- `user-scalable=no` — Может ли пользователь менять масштаб? Лючше ставить YES. Ибо читать громадные буквы не прикольно.
- `width=device-width` — ширина документа. Как раз тут должна быть такая запись, чтобы буквы не масштабировались браузером. Этот параметр вам нужно выставить и проверить. Мне помогло в хроме на мобилах некоторых.

У меня было `width=1028px`. Менюшки и футер мелкими, а контент-часть громадным шрифтом с регулировкой пользовательской. Поменял как выше для устройства — все хорошо стало. Успеха!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте на блоки в которых лежит запрещенный к масштабированию контент повесить max-heigth:9001em; Мне помогло. Вешал на body- не помогло. А на отдельных блоках работает. Почему работает - вообще не понимаю, но работает -факт.
http://tradebenefit.ru/chrome-pod-android-menyaet-shrifty-css

Answer (score 0):

Работает height: 100% для блока.

Comment: Поподробнее бы.

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?